# Error handling with data tables

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a for loop with a data table and I'm trying to figure out if a data table has no rows in it. Does it ignore the fact that there are no rows in it and move on or does it fail and give and exception? Here's the code for my loop, but this question should be the same in all cases.

```
  For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
      If Not IsDBNull(dr.Item("MATERIALID")) And dr.Item("MATERIALID") IsNot Nothing Then
          listOfResults.Add(CUInt(dr.Item("MATERIALID")))
      Else
          Trace.TraceError("Error Details: {0} Stack: {1}", "The materialID is nothing/null", System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString)
      End If
 Next
```

Comment: Would I be missing something if I suggested checking for `dt.Rows.Count() = 0`?

Answer (score 2):

if datatable has no rows then it will hit the for loop and exit and execute very next statement after for loop.
Note : but if datatable dt is nothing then it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Our strategy is to check if datatable is nothing AND if it has rows.  It knocks out both conditions in one if statement.

```
if not dt is nothing andalso dt.hasrows then
    'loop here
end if
```

Comment: Ok but if the data table has no rows and it hits it, what would happen? Would it fail and just send out an exception?

Comment: No exception there. Andalso will check dt.hasrows only if dt is not nothing. If first part is false the statement is false.

Comment: @Engerlost is correct.  My development team uses this as the standard when checking for a value on a variable that can be nothing.  We always make sure variable is NOT nothing before trying to check its value.